# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html, web

This code is intended to prompt a user to input five numerical values and to output their total value.

```
<script>
var total, number;
for (var count = 1, count < 5; count = count + 1)
{
number = parse Float(window.prompt('please enter a number', ''))
}
total = total + number;
document.write('the sum of your five numbers is' total)
</script>
```

What's wrong with that? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ! I think you should tell us first what you think is wrong so as we can help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var total = 0, num;
for (var count = 1; count <= 5; count = count + 1)
{
num = parseFloat(window.prompt('please enter a number', ''));
total += num;
}
document.write('the sum of your five numbers is'+total);
</script>
```

First :
The variable `toatal` must be initialized with value 0 . otherwise `total+=num` will add `num` with garbage value.

second : 
the `num` should be added inside the loop else it will add last input value only.
third : 
don't use `number` -> it is a keyword
fourth : 
no space between `parseFloat`
fifth : 
<= must be put inorder to get 5 numbers
last but not least : 
don't put comma (,) instead of semicolon (;) inside for loop
That is the exact problem

Comment: `number` isn't a keyword. Are you thinking of the `Number()` function? JS is case-sensitive, so `number` and `Number` are not the same.

Comment: note like that number is a reserved word actually. instead of int, number is in javascript. try typeof 123;

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, that doesn't make the word reserved.

Comment: See the list of reserved keywords in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar it doesn't mention `number`.

Comment: I didn't mean in such a way. It is not a good practice. That's all Just leave it

Comment: Oh, i eventually understand.

Answer (score 1):

You put `,` after `count = 1` but should be `;`.
Also `parse Float` = `parseFloat`, and when you printing at the end of code should be `numbers is' + total)` the `+`.

Now all works

```
var total, number;
for (var count = 1; count < 5; count = count + 1)
{
number = parseFloat(window.prompt('please enter a number', ''))
}
total = total + number;
document.write('the sum of your five numbers is' + total)
```